# How to disable holidays in datepicker in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker in my Rails app. I would like to disable business holidays in the datepicker. How do I do it?

(I have a table `MyDates` which has the list of all business days (does NOT contain holidays). Would I be able to use this to enable only business days in my `datepicker`?)

```
<input type="text" value= <%=MyDates.where("as_of_date<?", Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")).first.as_of_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %> class="datepicker" id="my_date_field"/>
```

Please help!

Comment: you can pass an array of dates to the [datesDisabled](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled) option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap - Datepicker/Disable specific dates from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830332/bootstrap-datepicker-disable-specific-dates-from-array)

Comment: can you please check this 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051207/how-to-disable-specific-dates-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/39265528' ,it is similar to your question.

Comment: @sovalina, @nandhini - thanks much for your inputs. Is there a `datesEnabled` option instead of `datesDisabled` option? I have a table that contains list of all business days in each row; I would like to select this table records and provide it to the datepicker. Is that poddible?

Comment: @m.beginner check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21146443/9541423) and this simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/6nxdpask/)