# bootstrap jquery datepicker disable all dates with exception and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need the help of a jquery guru :)

I'm trying to teach myself some javascript (bootstrap datepicker), but I'm failing because of the following:

I am currently reading the blocked days (json format) from a file use it as blocked dates in my datepicker, it works great:

---

javascript code:

```
 $("#picker1").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            updateViewDate: false,
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
            startDate: '+1d'
        }).on('show', function(e) {
            var setid = 12;
            var pickedMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth() + 1;
            var pickedYear = new Date(e.date).getFullYear();  
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_block_date.php',
                data:'sid='+ setid + '&m='+pickedMonth+'&y='+pickedYear,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST'
            })
                .done(function( response ) {
                    
                    $('#picker1').datepicker("setDatesDisabled", response.disableDates);
                })
                .fail(function(response, jqxhr, textStatus, error) {

                 $('#picker1').datepicker('remove');
                 alert('loading blockeddates failed');   

            }); 
            
        }).on('changeMonth', function (e) {

    
         }).on('changeDate', function(e) {

        });
```

the json looks like this:

```
[ "2021-09-30", "2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03", "2021-10-04" ]
```

---

my question:

now I would like to turn it around:

I have a new json file in which the days are listed which should be the only ones activated AND i have a separator next to the date for an special id. if the dates is chosen, the id should be able to be processed.

my json file:

```
[ "2021-09-29|2", "2021-09-28|3", "2021-09-27|2" ]
```

my task:

- every day except for those should be blocked, every month the list should be queried again
- it should be the parameter after the separator | further processed via javascript.

hope you help me ;)
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? ([ask])

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830332/bootstrap-datepicker-disable-specific-dates-from-array